# Sudo says "command not found" for script in EncFS (no root access to EncFS mount?)

Tags: permissions, sudo, fuse, command-not-found, encfs

When an encrypted directory is mounted using [EncFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EncFS) as a regular user, you cannot execute a script in it with sudo (as root):

```
$ sudo /run/media/yeti/usbdrive/encfs/test.sh
sudo: /run/media/yeti/usbdrive/encfs/test.sh: command not found
```

This is a security feature, but how can I still grant root permissions to this mounted directory (without mounting as root)?

## More details

I am using [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/), and I have an encrypted directory using [EncFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EncFS):

```
sudo pacman -S encfs
usbpath="/run/media/yeti/usbdrive"
encfs "$usbpath/.encfs" "$usbpath/encfs"
echo 'echo hello world' > "$usbpath/encfs/test.sh"
sudo chmod +x "$usbpath/encfs/test.sh"
```

Then this command works just like expected:

```
$ /run/media/yeti/usbdrive/encfs/test.sh
hello world
```

But when I use sudo, I get an error:

```
$ sudo /run/media/yeti/usbdrive/encfs/test.sh
sudo: /run/media/yeti/usbdrive/encfs/test.sh: command not found
```

Then I realized that this is a security feature of EncFS, which is actually quite good. When I do a directory listing as `root` (after `su`), I find the following:

```
$ ls /run/media/yeti/usbdrive/encfs/
ls: cannot access '/run/media/yeti/usbdrive/encfs': Permission denied
[...]
d?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ?  encfs
drwxrwxrwx  1 yeti yeti     0 Sep 30 00:31  .encfs
[...]
```

But in my case, I am on a system where I am in fact root, and where sudo could be passwordless. Therefore, this security feature is only getting in the way. However, I do not want to mount the encrypted directory as root either (because then I'd need to run my filemanager and other applications as root too).

What I did as a workaround to this problem is to copy the file outside of the encrypted directory (`cp "$usbpath/encfs/test.sh" /tmp/test.sh`), and then execute it as root (`sudo /tmp/test.sh`).

Next to documenting this question for other people who may experience the same issue, the question I still have left is: Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encfs uses fuse under the hood.  It includes an `-o` option to pass options to fuse.  Adding `-o allow_root` will allow root to access the filesystem in addition to the user mounting (also note the similar but exclusive `allow_others` flag).  To use this option, you will need to enable it in fuse config.  In `/etc/fuse.conf`, add the `user_allow_other` directive

See [mount.fuse(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.fuse.8.html) and [encfs(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/encfs)

Comment: Thank you, adding `user_allow_other` to `/etc/fuse.conf` and then using `encfs -o allow_root` works.